# Which will execute first (PHP)?

Tags: php

I have a function right here:

```
function loginForm($post){
    $username = c($post['username']);
    $password = md5(c($post['password']));
    if($this->login($username,$password))
        $this->setCookies($post);
}
```

As you can see the username and password are returned from a function called 
`c()` (which is just `$mysqli->real_escape_string()`).

Now, as you can see in the password field, there are 2 functions.

```
$password = md5(c($post['password']));
```

My question is, will the `c()` function run first, or the `md5` function will run first?  I'm almost sure the `c()` function is running first, but I'm not sure.

Comment: You're right :-)

Comment: Always top to down, and inner to outer.

Comment: Of course c() will run first. Otherwise how md5 will get an argument?

Comment: Md5 execute last, because need the input given by the C() function.

Comment: Alright guys - we have enough answers now. We don't need more than 5 answers to say "Yes, c() runs first".

Comment: This is the kind of question that will garner 20 answers and comments within a minute. I should learn to avoid these :)

Comment: Just upvote the oldest `correct` answer and move on.

Comment: This type of question get too much attention and the first answer gets highest vote!!

Comment: All aboard the karma train!

Comment: Thank you all guys, i'll upvote the oldest correct answer.

Comment: I would hate to be the developer that has to remember what function `c` does.

Comment: @AlexP It's obvious what it does. It converts whatever argument you parse into the letter `c`. It's the only thing that makes sense.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`c` runs first.

Because you can rewrite it to:

```
$temp = c($post['password']);
$password = md5($temp);
```

You can not rewrite it so that `md5` is called first.

Answer (score 4):

The c function will run first.

Answer (score 3):

```
$password = md5(c($post['password']));
```

is equivalent to

```
$password_c = c($post['password']);
$password = md5($password_c);
```

so `c` will run first.

Answer (score 2):

the `c()` function runs first. In case of a function inside another function, the outer function (in this case `md5()`) will be first pushed to the [stack](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_%28abstract_data_type%29). Then the inner function (`c()`) will execute. Then, `c()`'s result is used as an input for the outer function (`md5()`) which is popped from the [stack](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_%28abstract_data_type%29) and executed.

Answer (score 1):

`c()` will be executed first, then `md5()`.